# Restarting tomcat after either one or both conditions true using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, tomcat, scripting

My script checks two conditions and it has to restart the server just once after one or both conditions are true. But I am not sure how to make it. Instead I made the script to restart the server twice. Actually, the script should restart the server after it adds the contents to the both files or at least one file. Please help me to complete this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -q -F 'grant codeBase "file:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/-"' /var/TomCat/tomcat/conf/catalina.policy
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo '// AppDynamics permissions
grant codeBase "file:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/-" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
};
' >> /var/TomCat/tomcat/conf/catalina.policy
  echo "Appdynamics code is successfully added to catalina.policy file"
  /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh ; sleep 10 ; /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
else
  echo "Appdynamics code is already added on catalina.policy file"
fi

grep -q -F 'javaagent:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/javaagent.jar' /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=YOUR_APPNAME -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=YOUR_TIERNAME -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=`hostname`""
    read -p "Enter the value for Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName : " n1
    read -p "Enter the value for Dappdynamics.agent.tierName= : " n2
    appname=$n1
    tiername=$n2
    echo 'export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName='$appname' -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName='$tiername' -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=`hostname`"' >> /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh
        /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh ; sleep 10 ; /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
else
  echo "AppDynamics Environment variable is already set on setenv.sh"
fi
```

Thanks,
Kumar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -q -F 'grant codeBase "file:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/-"' /var/TomCat/tomcat/conf/catalina.policy
my_first_status=$?
if [ ${my_first_status} -ne 0 ]; then
  echo '// AppDynamics permissions
grant codeBase "file:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/-" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
};
' >> /var/TomCat/tomcat/conf/catalina.policy
  echo "Appdynamics code is successfully added to catalina.policy file"
  #/var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh ; sleep 10 ; /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
else
  echo "Appdynamics code is already added on catalina.policy file"
fi

grep -q -F 'javaagent:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/javaagent.jar' /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh
my_second_status=$?
if [ ${my_second_status} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=YOUR_APPNAME -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=YOUR_TIERNAME -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=`hostname`""
    read -p "Enter the value for Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName : " n1
    read -p "Enter the value for Dappdynamics.agent.tierName= : " n2
    appname=$n1
    tiername=$n2
    echo 'export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName='$appname' -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName='$tiername' -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=`hostname`"' >> /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh
        #/var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh ; sleep 10 ; /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
else
  echo "AppDynamics Environment variable is already set on setenv.sh"
fi

if [ ${my_first_status} -ne 0 ] || [ ${my_second_status} -ne 0 ];then
 /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh ; sleep 10 ; /var/TomCat/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
fi
```

Comment: Thank you Digvijay.